# Pandas Dataframe to_csv format output

Tags: python, pandas, format, dataframe

I can't find a way to control the output of each column dataframe. From the following code:

```
df.to_csv('dfnc.txt', 
        sep=' ', 
        float_format='%.8f',
        cols=['cycle','passs','ip','lon','lat'],
        index=False)
```

I'm getting this:

```
1.00000000 1.00000000 543.00000000 23.15881870 -64.70485950
1.00000000 1.00000000 544.00000000 23.10356160 -64.64569150
1.00000000 1.00000000 545.00000000 23.04852510 -64.58650550
1.00000000 1.00000000 546.00000000 22.99370760 -64.52730150
1.00000000 1.00000000 547.00000000 22.93910770 -64.46807990
```

And I want this:

```
1 1 543 23.15881870 -64.70485950
1 1 544 23.10356160 -64.64569150
1 1 545 23.04852510 -64.58650550
1 1 546 22.99370760 -64.52730150
1 1 547 22.93910770 -64.46807990
```

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just convert the 1st to the 3rd `columns` to `int64` before writing the CSV file (if you check the `.types`, I am sure they are all `float64`):

```
df[['cycle', 'passs', 'ip']]=df[['cycle', 'passs', 'ip']].astype(int64)
```

Comment: You're right about .types, they were all float64. Your solution worked like a charm! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: What if you want to control the decimal places in the float output?